# MySQL Set 0 if null (SUM CASE) doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count of condition from all employees of each area, which conditions has 2 parameters, WELL AND UNWELL. Like this,

```
conditions    |    area    |    count_conditions
   Well           AREA1               1
  UNWELL          AREA1               0
   Well           AREA2               5
  UNWELL          AREA2               1
...
```

This is the closest so far.

```
SELECT a.conditions, k.area, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN a.conditions IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_conditions
FROM tb_attended a
INNER JOIN tb_employees k ON a.nrp = k.nrp
    AND a.date = '2020-07-20'
GROUP BY k.area, a.conditions
```

My code above is running well, but if there is no entry of UNWELL OR WELL in some area, then that conditions does not appear. Like this.

```
conditions    |    area    |    count_conditions
   Well           AREA1               1
   Well           AREA2               5
  UNWELL          AREA2               1
...
```

This is example data that I use,
[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8059b81/3)

Any suggest?
**Thank you.**

Comment: You have two tables in the query.  It is not clear what you are showing in your questino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a CROSS join of the distinct areas to the distinct conditions and then LEFT joins of the tables:

```
SELECT t1.condition, t2.area, 
       COUNT(k.nrp) AS count_conditions
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `condition` FROM tb_attended) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Area FROM tb_employees) t2
LEFT JOIN tb_attended a ON a.condition = t1.condition
LEFT JOIN tb_employees k ON k.area = t2.area AND a.nrp = k.nrp AND a.date = '2020-07-20'
GROUP BY t1.condition, t2.area
ORDER BY t2.area, t1.condition DESC
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a2a34e8ca6642b3752881c86b60356c7).

Answer (score 0):

Use left join

```
SELECT a.conditions, k.area, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN a.conditions IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_conditions
FROM tb_attended a
left JOIN tb_employees k
ON a.nrp = k.nrp
AND a.date = '2020-07-20'
GROUP BY k.area, a.conditions
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your fast response, I've tried your suggest with `LEFT JOIN`, and it produced additional row for total of each conditions, but doesn't display for area with conditions has zero value

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `left join`:

```
SELECT a.conditions, k.area, COUNT(a.conditions) AS count_conditions
FROM tb_employees k LEFT JOIN
     tb_attended a
     ON a.nrp = k.nrp AND a.date = '2020-07-20'
GROUP BY k.area, a.conditions;
```

EDIT:

I see.  You want to get all rows, even those with no matches.  Use a `CROSS JOIN` to generate the combinations of areas and conditions that you want.  Then use `LEFT JOIN` to match to the existing data:

```
SELECT c.condition, e.area, COUNT(a.nrp) AS count_conditions
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.condition 
      FROM tb_attended a
     ) c CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT area
      FROM tb_employees
     ) e LEFT JOIN
     tb_employees k
     ON k.area = e.area LEFT JOIN
     tb_attended a
     ON a.nrp = k.nrp AND 
        a.condition = c.condition AND
        a.date = '2020-07-20'
GROUP BY c.condition, e.area;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=170f722ce1202f1d64eb95fc5ae573db) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your fast response, I've tried your suggest and use your code, the results are same as mine. It doesn't display for area with conditions has zero value

Comment: @Rion . . . Sample data and desired results would really help, as I alluded to in my comment (but wasn't explicit).  A db/sql fiddle is also useful.

Comment: I just attach example data on SQL fiddle with my update above. And for desire result just like in my question. Those tables above are showing the result of query that I want. Sorry if that's not clear to you.

Comment: yes, that is result exactly what I want to achieve. thank you so much. never think to use cross join though.

Comment: @Rion . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  It was answered many hours before the other one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff your edit which provided the correct solution was given hours after the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` without redundant conditional statement, with `SUM()` aggregation :

```
SELECT a.conditions, k.area, 
       SUM(a.conditions IS NOT NULL) AS count_conditions
  FROM tb_attended a
  LEFT JOIN tb_employees k
    ON a.nrp = k.nrp
   AND a.date = '2020-07-20'
 GROUP BY k.area, a.conditions
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your fast response, I've tried your suggest and use your code, and it produced additional row for total of each conditions, but doesn't display for area with conditions has zero value

Comment: you're welcome @Rion . Do you need something like [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e01e3c/3) ..?